# Expressing the short time that passed since I received some information

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say something recently happened (Alice called Bob) and a few seconds ago someone told me that Alice called Bob.

What's the most natural way to express this:

- I just knew that Alice called Bob
- I just realized that Alice called Bob
- I just got to know that Alice called Bob (this seems to imply that "I need to know that Alice called Bob" but what I just want is to use the past of "to get")
- other possible ways to say?

Thank you
W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

> I *just* **found out** that Alice called Bob.

or

> I **was** *just* **told** that Alice called Bob.

However,

> I *just* **realized** that Alice called Bob.

means that you had some (indirect information), which lead you to understand that Alice called Bob, without anybody explicitly telling you so.

Your other examples are not proper English, even though grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

'I just' is the right way to start, but...

'I just knew' is generally incorrect.
'I just realised' conflicts with the scenario - somebody told you, you didn't simply realise it.
'Get to know' would imply 'had the opportunity to learn', and even so sounds awkward (see the various meanings of get to know).

How about 'I was just told' or 'I just heard' or 'I just found out'?